# Scaffold-DbContext: Underscores eliminates while generating Context from postgres Database in .NetCore

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework-core, ef-database-first, asp.net-core-scaffolding

I am using the latest EFCore version with the Postgres database using the DB First approach. While generating Dbcontext from an existing Postgres database it eliminates underscore ('_') from the table name and also from the column names.

[Database table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KT6gm.png)

[Generated DbContext model structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJaGn.png)

I am using the following command to generate DbContext:

`Scaffold-DbContext "Server=localhost;Port=5432;User Id=postgres;Password=mypassword;Database=SAMPLE_db;" Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL -o DbModels -Schemas "local_dev"`

Comment: And the problem is...? There must be a generated fluent configuration associating the correct table/column names with standard for C# Pascal naming class/property names, so in C# you will use the natural for C# names, and they will be mapped to your (obsolete) database naming convention.

Comment: But if you insist, pass [-UseDatabaseNames](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/powershell#scaffold-dbcontext) option to `Scaffold-DbContext` command.

Comment: Use this package https://github.com/efcore/EFCore.NamingConventions

Answer (score 1):

As Ivan Stove mentioned above, use the dbcontext scaffold `--use-database-names` argument.  This will remove things like underscores from both table names and fields.

Here's an example using the terminal:

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "server=*SQL Server name*;user=*user name*;password=*password*;database=*database name*" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -o Models -t *table name 1* -t *table name 2* -t *table name x* -f **--use-database-names**
```

Notes:

- `-o Models`: The folder in your solution you want the model files to be written to.  It needs to already exist.
- `-t Individual table`: This is handy is you only want a subset of tables to have models generated.
  Just repeat the `-t` for each table

Answer (score 0):

This is now fixed in latest version of EF.
Use the `-UseDatabaseNames` option

see here [Scaffold-DbContext is not generating column as same in Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70951447/scaffold-dbcontext-is-not-generating-column-as-same-in-table)