# Scaffold-DbContext is not generating column as same in Table

Tags: asp.net, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, c#-4.0

I used `Scaffold-DbContext` to generate entity class. It's generating class but removed underscore from properties (table's column), also followed the camel case.

Example:

column name `RT_UNIQUE` changed to `RtUnique`

column name `D_DISTRICT` changed to `DDistrict`

I know the naming convention are not correct. But these are oracle tables and can't be modified for now.

Is there any flag/option need to set `Scaffold-DbContext` command to keep the same column name as in table.

Comment: The column name is still used  as you can see in the DbContext class

Comment: @ErikEJ.  Yes. I see inside OnModelCreatring()
         entity.Property(e => e.RtUnique)
                    .HasColumnName("RT_UNIQUE");   
But how should prevent from happening. there are 30 tables.

Comment: You can try UseDatabasenames option - if that does not work, you can try the Naming Conventions Nuget package

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- -UseDatabasenames option works.